# How to change font of controls in workItem form in VS2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-workitem

Is there any way to change the font of controls in `workitem` form in VS2013.

I have searched the net and I have looked at VisualStudio font options, but I couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible in VS, in the web access you could use something like grease monkey to redo the style.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on MSDN forums indicating that this was the Font > Environmental Font. I applied a change and confirmed this worked in Visual Studio 2015. This means, however, that if you change the font, it changes everywhere.

I've provided a helpful guide on how to use it to the best advantage.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The font in the work item from is controlled by the font within Visual Studio. If you open up "Tools | Options" and then look for "Environment | Fonts & Colours" you can customise any of the fonts used within the IDE.

Comment: Thanks,I have checked before, none of them in related to this. Can you tell which one exactly?

Comment: @MrHinsh if you could update this i'd love to flag it up. I can't find it either